# Catching Mouse Wheel Scroll inside Non-scrollable Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, event-handling, jquery-events

Is there a way to catch the scroll event while mouse is positioned over a `div` that is not scrollable?  My intent is to feign scrolling by adjusting top offset until `div` inside of `div` is above view then move top offset of inner `div` to below view of outer `div`.  Kind of like a carousel, but vertical and controlled by scrolling of the mouse wheel.  Obviously, to catch scroll events, I would use:

```
angular.element(elem).find('.divClass').bind('scroll', function(){...});
```

to handle scrolling that is actually occurring, but I'm interested in when the actual mouse wheel is scrolled much like a keybind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the onwheel event. see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onwheel.asp

some browsers use onmousehweel. for a good tutorial see https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/

Comment: that won't work for finger scrolling on touch devices, right?