# Jquery - Binding the actual scroll wheel activity (not body scroll height) to the scrolling of a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

Ok so here is what I am trying to do. I have a "frame" for the content on my website that is scrollable, with a sidebar that is fixed to the left side. In some user testing, users were saying they want to be able to scroll through the framed content from anywhere on the page (currently you can only scroll through the frame when your cursor is over the frame). However, since the sidebar area is not scrollable, I don't think tracking the body's scrollHeight as a variable and assigning it to the frame div will work. That's all I can think of right now, and I have this code:

```
$(body).scroll(function(){
               var s = body.scrollHeight;
                $("#content").scroll(s);
            });
```

I know that's kind of a mess but I'm a little lost on how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

TLDR: I want to bind the action of scrolling anywhere on the page, regardless of whether or not the div is scrollable, to the scrolling of a specific div.

Comment: Can you add a [mcve]?

Comment: I guess the issue is that I don't really know what I need to be doing for this to work. There isn't an "issue" with the code per se, it's just that I don't know the correct way to do what I'm attempting.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107394/catching-mouse-wheel-scroll-inside-non-scrollable-div

Comment: Thank you, this is very close to what I need. All I need now is to know how to force a div to scroll. Can I do something like $("#div").scrollHeight(x) where x is defined by the "wheel" event listener?

Comment: actually it looks like this is not quite what I need. The "wheel" listener treats the mouse wheel as a single press, meaning it doesn't capture whether you are scrolling up or down and how much you are scrolling.